# Pytorch code breaks on Collab when shifting from T4 to A100

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I need to run a CNN and to perform some fine-tuning. My code works okay when I use a T4 GPU, but it breaks when I try to switch to an A100. I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type
> (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

I'm using a pretrained Resnet model available on Pytorch and editing the last layers. It seems as if I had a Cuda-CPU conflict, but why does it work on a T4 then?

Any insights?

Below a preview of my code; the full code is available
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KMbgeHa1BBbDZmvSAYeFL358hWhSr0wF/view?usp=sharing):

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

net = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

#fine-tuning
for param in net.parameters():
    param.requires_grad= False

net.fc=nn.Linear(512*4, num_classes)

net.to(device)

#training
learning_rate=0.005
num_epochs=10
batch_size=50

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train Network
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    losses = []

    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
        # Get data to cuda if possible
        data = data.to(device=device)
        targets = targets.to(device=device)

        # forward
        scores = net(data)
        #scores = net(data).to(device=device)
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)

        losses.append(loss.item())
        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # gradient descent or adam step
        optimizer.step()

    print(f"Cost at epoch {epoch} is {sum(losses)/len(losses):.5f}")

# Check accuracy on training & test to see how good our model


def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    if loader.dataset.train:
        print("Checking accuracy on training data")
    else:
        print("Checking accuracy on test data")

    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in loader:
            x = x.to(device=device)
            y = y.to(device=device)

            scores = model(x)
            _, predictions = scores.max(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)

        print(
            f"Got {num_correct} / {num_samples} with accuracy {float(num_correct)/float(num_samples)*100:.2f}"
        )

    model.train()


check_accuracy(train_loader, net)
```

Comment: The issue is caused by a tensor on CPU interacting with a tensor on GPU. Somewhere in the code, something is on CPU and not getting moved to GPU. Hard to say without details on the stack trace